# Compiling or using libxml using C on OSX

Tags: c, macos, libxml2

If I want to compile a c source file that uses libxml, how do I setup libxml on mac osx so that my source file will just compile correctly and be ready to run?

I have been using XCode until now, but have switched to TextMate & Terminal, Do I need to create a makefile if I want to use libxml or how will this work?

Thanks

EDIT:

I use the current imports

```
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
```

Comment: Best thing to do is type: `locate xmlmemory.h` -- then copy the root folder location, paste it after `-I` to include the root folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The headers for the libxml2 distribution on 10.6 resides within `/usr/include/libxml2/`. Unfortunately, just the `/usr/include` part is within the system default header search path. Thus, you need to explicitly include it on the command line (or have your `#includes` also include the additional libxml2 folder).  The library itself resides at the usual `/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib`.

Thus, use the following command to compile your program:

```
gcc source.c -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -o output
```

Answer (score 3):

No setup required.  Add `-lxml2` to your link command.

If you just have a simple single-source file "project":

```
gcc yourSourceFile.c -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -o executableProgram
```

Comment: I get errors like the following when trying it. gcc ParsingTestCode.c -lxml2 -o parser ParsingTestCode.c:4:30: error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory ParsingTestCode.c:5:27: error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @Helium3: Add `-I/usr/include/libxml2` to your header search paths.

Answer (score 2):

You can also xml2-config to get the compilation flags to use.

```
kjp@vbox:~/Dev/ScratchDir$ xml2-config --cflags --libs
-I/usr/include/libxml2
-lxml2
kjp@vbox:~/Dev/ScratchDir$
```

Answer (score 2):

I vote for Kjp's answer with a simple modification.
How about include the xml2-config to the gcc command itself -

g++ -o bin_name `xml2-config --cflags`  main.c `xml2-config --libs`

This should work even if libxml is not installed on the default location OR the flag name is changed (in future).

CHEERS!